# Run sudo command without password prompt

Tags: node.js, electron, sudo

I have this electron app that executes a sudo command and I don;t want it to prompt for the sudo password each time so I added the path to that command in the sudoers file:

`user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/program`

Once the program is packaged and installed, the program fails to start because sudo requires a tty: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`. If I run the app from the terminal it works (doh).

Using something like `electron-sudo` does not solve the problem. That package will ask for sudo password each time is invoked. I use it to only ask for password once so I can setup the sudoers file and then user regular exec with sudo.

Is there a way of executing a sudo command without password prompt in nodejs/electron, considering that the program is whitelisted in sudoers?

Comment: Ever figure this out? I'm looking for the same thing